# After clicking add to cart, the URL has ?add-to-cart=1234 behind it

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

When I click the add to cart button, the page refreshes and adds the ?add-to-cart=1234 at the end of the URL. This makes it that all add to cart buttons (on the product category page btw) contain that url (/product-category/baby/?add-to-cart=1234). So if I click the add to cart for a product again I get /product-category/baby/?add-to-cart=1234?add-to-cart=5678.

I've tried many codes that sort of redirects/refreshes the page to the same product category URL (without the add to cart link obviously), but I'm not proficient enough to actually understand what I'm doing regarding this.

So I would like to know how I can stay on the same page/refresh the page after add to cart so that ?add-to-cart=1234 is not in the URL.

If that's not possible, is there something in the JS code which isn't correct?
Here the code:

```
function(){if(0!==t(".ragnar_products_olivia").length){var a=window.location.href;t("#page-container .ragnar_products_olivia .et_pb_shop li.product").each(function(){for(var i,e=t(this).attr("class").split(" "),s=0;s<e.length;s++)if(e[s].indexOf("post-")>-1){i=e[s].slice("post-".length,e[s].length);break}t('<a class="add_to_cart ajax_add_to_cart" href="'+a+"?add-to-cart="+i+'"></a>').appendTo(t(this).find(".price")),t(this).find(".et_overlay").appendTo(t(this).find(".price")),t(this).hasClass("sale")&&t(this).find(".price del").insertAfter(t(this).find(".onsale"));var r=t(this).find(".et_shop_image img").attr("src"),o=t(this).find(".et_shop_image img").attr("srcset");o=(r=r.replace(/-([0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9])\w+/g,"")).replace(/-([0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9])\w+/g,""),t(this).find(".et_shop_image img").attr("src",r),t(this).find(".et_shop_image img").attr("srcset",o)}),t('<div class="product_filter"><ul><li class="active_menu_item" postClass="all">All Work</li></ul></div>').insertBefore(".ragnar_products_olivia .et_pb_shop");var i="product_cat-",e=[];t("#page-container .ragnar_products_olivia li.product").each
```

One of the codes I tried is this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect');
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect($url) {
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: please add the **relevant** code to the question

Comment: Click [edit], then the button shaped like `[<>]` and post only enough code for a [mcve]

Comment: Did you turn on ajax add to cart option in your Woocommerce settings ? That should fix your problems unless there is modification on your buttons etc.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about the code image not allowed. I've pasted a part of the code that it concerns.

Ajax Add To Cart is turned on in the WooCommerce settings.

Reference page: https://jc.levelupwebdesign.nl/product-category/baby/

Comment: _"Ajax Add To Cart is turned on in the WooCommerce settings"_ - but it doesn't actually appear to be working; browser dev tools clearly show that clicking on the buttons causes a normal navigation request, and not an AJAX request. Maybe your theme is not properly set up for AJAX add-to-cart.